# What are Maven plugin extractors?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, extractor

In the configuration of a maven plugin's build, where you are specifying configuration for the "maven-plugin-plugin" there is something called an extractor. I also see it when building the plugin (`Applying extractor for language: java`).

In [this page](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/) it specifies many different extractors, but doesn't give a very clear explanation of what they are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extractor in that meaning is responsible for extracting the description of the plugin like parameters, injectors etc. which is defined by [javadoc things like](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-java/index.html) or [annotations](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-annotations/index.html) or [for ant like plugins](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-model/plugin-metadata.html):

```
@parameter
@goal
```

They exists currently for Java and BeanShell.